# Monitor/logging who signs into the asp.netapp?

Tags: asp.net

I want to have a log file keep rows of who logs in and timestamp. is there a place to do this? And what sort of code is needed?

Comment: You should hash your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

The default MembershipProvider can let you know when was the last time that a given User logged in to your site.
Look at [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx). It has the following properties that might be of use for you:

```
MembershipUser.LastActivityDate
MembershipUser.LastLoginDate
```

.
If you are using webforms you can suscribe to the [Login.LoggedIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx) event of the Login Control. In your callback function you can then log the login to your persitant store (database table, xml file, ...).

If you are not using the login control you could also register a handler for the [HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx). This would also work for asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

On the Login module/page on your site add the **OnLoggedIn** the **OnLoggingIn** and the **OnLoginError** , and there log your users.

In this functions, you can get the user name by find the UserName control

```
TextBox txtUserName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
```

or if the user have been logged in, by the sender infos

```
protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //-> ((Login)sender).UserName
}
```

Then log your users - the datetime of login is of cource the **DateTine.Now**